# Reading in a text file and splitting it's contents - can only post each line?

Tags: java, arrays, readfile

I'm attempting to read in a text file and output it, which is done, however each line is stored in a different part of the array, so the first line is [0] and so on, I'm trying to split the first line up so the first word in the first line is [0], the second is [1], etc. Here is the code I have so far, any help would be much appreciated.

public class main {

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String matchResults = "P:/SD/Assignment1/results.txt";

    try
    {
        readfile txtFile = new readfile(matchResults);          
        String[] lineArray = txtFile.openMatchResults();

        int i;
        for (i=0; i < lineArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(lineArray[i]);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 2D array called `text`, with one dimension corresponding to lineNumbers and the second to words of each line. Like that:

```
String[][] text = new String[lineArray.length][];        
for (int i = 0; i < lineArray.length; ++i) {
    text[i] = lineArray[i].split(" "); //now each text[i] is an Array with the words of line i
}

for (String[] wordsOfaLine : text) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wordsOfaLine));
}
```

Assuming that words are delimited by a blank space.
The resulting String array `text` has the first word of the first line in `text[0][0]`, the second word of the first line in `text[0][1]`, the third word of the second line in `text[1][2]`, and so on...